# How to start bash subshell without environment but with .bashrc

Tags: bash

I'd like a create a bash subshell that does not inherit any changes I've made to my environment. Basically I want my environment in the subshell to be how it was at login.

I thought

```
env -i bash
```

might work but I get the following error

```
dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
```

My guess is bash is trying to load my.bashrc file and fails because it's missing some environment variables that were set at login.

Comment: How about `exec -i bash -li`

Comment: What does exec's -i flag do? The man page doesn't list it as an option

Comment: I mean the flag passed to exec, as in exec -i

Comment: Sorry, I meant `env`, not `exec`. typo

Answer (score 0):

You can print the scripts called by bash upon login using

```
echo exit | strace bash -li |& less | grep '^open'
```

running these scripts after `env -i bash` seem to work